# Google places to access Google plus data

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Google Places autocomplete Api  in some cases does not return data that I would like to see.

Try to open https://maps.google.com/maps, enter "Centennial Olympic Park" and check autocomplete options. All these options are some street location and have not much data inside (no images, no reviews) if you select any of them. Although Google Map will show you right Centennial Olympic Park place if you click Enter button. That place is connected to Google Plus and contains much more information.

See image below:

[image]

Rectangle A Shows autocomplete places (I can get them but that is not what I want)

Rectangle B shows Google Maps result (I cannot get it but that is what I want)

Users of my applications needs possibility to have result B in autocomplete list.

Any idea how that can be achieved?

**Update:**

Google Places Text Search API returns required Place.

reference of park is "CoQBdAAAAFls6sJIkf__0U99uBOmIn6vNg_5IbbIdMpNzaDOeVkQbrRZ6OmGXAHgxmGITFxPlq3Cv-SQMYuUrfgGM-1XYECjwic8oZG9i9l3fgPiWEJqyCNEwFkj4118ESiEYQkdzs23O3IzyB_aOzP4AQqlemPA-eXEICodv96AmnTKcnwmEhDyyTqn7IFW8w5P75IG9YmfGhRjQj8l-TV_6v3rEeecJM8VRx-Vvg"

Details are seen in Details API.

Question is still open - How I can see places like that in Places Autocomplete API?

Comment: Perhaps adding types=establishment to your autocomplete request, if you're not including it already, will help filter out the streets and focus on business-type places?

Comment: @pushbit: I tried establishment and that does not help. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete